# API Authentication for multiple apps

Tags: api, authentication, oauth

I have been doing a lot of research into how to authenticate mobile apps with an API - I still feel a bit unsure about which flow & architecture would be better to use in my particular use case.

I think what's confusing me is some of the terminology used.

My use case:

- An API & database on one server. Which holds the users & and the users resources.
- A web app, which I have built and consumes the API. Hosted on the same server as the API. So it's dogfooding.
- A web app, which I have built and consumes the API. Hosted on a different server to the API.
- A mobile app, which I have built and consumes the API.

I'd like to be able to authenticate with the API using username & password.

The API will never be opened up for consumption by other 3rd party services except the web app and the mobile app.

Initially I felt like using the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow would be sufficient. However in the docs it states that this flow should be used if "The client is absolutely trusted with the user credentials".

Since both my mobile & web apps will be built by me, I'm assuming they are seen as 1st party clients. Therefore am I right in thinking they are considered to be trusted with the user credentials? As I typically thought that when implementing oAuth, the idea would be to have the authentication server separate from the resource server. Which would allow you to have one authentication server for multiple APIs.

After reading this post: [Why the Password Grant is not suitable for modern applications](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)

It threw me off track a bit. But then, is this post talking about using this flow in my use case?

I was also looking at the Implicit Grant Tokens flow. However using this flow I couldn't really see how the user would enter their credentials first?

I also question if any of the oAuth flows is really needed for my use case and I should instead look at other ways of authenticating?

I'm really quite lost with this I would like some direction to go in with how to authenticate users in my particular case.

Thanks in advance!

- I'll most likely be using Laravel to house my API and so I do have Passport available to me to implement oAuth

**EDIT**

From following this [oauth article](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/) I've found that in all use cases of my app, I end at Password Credentials Grant flow. Would I be correct here?

Comment: basically you are correct. oAuth can be good choice. note that the web app can use authentication code grant, and the mobile app can use "password" grant... i have lectured on oAuth (hebrew), if it interests you... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnMbLm6wa5k

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I do not understand hebrew.

Comment: So the web app can use auth code grant, but will also be okay with password grant? or the web app should use auth code grant

Comment: the web app should better be auth-code grant... the password grant is for use case such as you described, when there is a trust between the app developer and the auth-server